# Is there a performance difference between custom server controls and user controls?

Tags: c#, user-controls, servercontrols

Consider two controls that do basically the same things. For instance, a gridview-like-widget with paging, sorting, and data caching. Both bound with the same 10,000 row data source. One is a custom server control and one is a user control. Is there any reason there would be any difference in performance?

Just wondering that the community thinks about this.

Comment: well, that would depend what's in them! Not a real question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the 2 controls contained identical code, there would not be any performance difference.  The difference between them is simply how the code is compiled (Usercontrols are compiled directly into the web application's dll, and server controls are compiled into their own dlls), and when they are compiled (by themselves or with the web application).

Once compiled, they are classes like any other.

Comment: 1.A usercontrol is actually a handler, so it makes an additional request to the server, could this somewhat impact performance? 2.What do you mean when you say "if they're compiled by themselves or with the web application"? How does a dll compile by itself?